# javascript typewriter not printing words

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I cant get my javascript type to print on the page, maybe im calling it wrong? Im using a rails app.

on the homepage using haml

```
.element Create and write something cool using javscript typewriter
```

in my js file

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["Create and write something cool using javscript typewriter "],
        typeSpeed: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: is any JS error in browser's console?

Comment: yes there is! Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add reference to `typed.js` after `jquery.js` as follows:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="typed.js"></script>
```

Comment: im supposed to put that in the html/haml homepage correct?

im getting this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/typed.js

Comment: yes..exactly...Just see how and where you have added the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` and put the needed `<script>` tag after that. Just make sure that you are using correct path (relative/absolute) of these .js files.

Comment: 404 error means you are giving wrong path. Please check how other .js or images are getting referred and I am sure you will solve this.

Comment: so like this?

 `<script src="jquery.js">`
     ` <script src="typed.js">`
      `.element Create and write something cool using javscript typewriter`
      `</script>`

Comment: sorry..but I don't know that much about ruby-rail application's folder structure. But i believe there has to be a master page which is having `jquery.js` library reference. Please try to find that and put the reference to 'typed.js' there.